# How to access a javascript function and elements from a different HTML page

Tags: javascript

I have a js function written in a jsp page that calculates the number of days between 2 dates:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function chk(d,e)
     {
      var x = d.split('/')
      var y = e.split('/')
      var a = new Date(x[2],x[0],x[1])
      var b = new Date(y[2],y[0],y[1])
      var c = ( b - a )
      var d = c / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
     }
    </script>
```

The same jsp page also has a text box:

```
    <input type="text" name="id">
```

I want to access the value calculated by js function i.e 'd' and the value of the textbox i.e.'id' from a different jsp page. How do I do it???

Comment: Unless you're opening the second, different JSP page in a window spawned by the main page, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a .js file and put the script into that and import js file using script tag in the filed you need javascript.

```
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```

Comment: how will i call the function from .js file to get the value 'd'??

Comment: You will pass value of d and e to function when you call it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the 2 methods, In first method you will be redirected to second page along with the values(d and id) but in second method, you can stay in 1st page while values will get submitted to the 2nd page.
**First**

You can create a `form` and put the `textfield` inside it and also a `hidden input field` which will carry the value of `d`.

```
<form action="2ndpage.jsp" method="POST" onsubmit="initializeVar()">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="d" id="id1">
<input type="text" id="id" name="text">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
  function initializeVar()
  {
    document.getElementById("id1").value=d;
  }
</script>
```

**SECOND**

You can use `ajax` for this purpose.

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    alert("values posted");
    }
  }
var text_box_text = document.getElementById("id");
var args = "?d=" + d + "&text=" + text_box_text;
xmlhttp.open("GET","2ndpage.jsp"+args,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Just look at **3rd, 4th and 5th** line from bottom.
When you want to send thos values to another page, just call the function `loadXMLDoc()`
In your `2ndpage.jsp`, you can retrieve those values by using

```
int date_diff = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("d"));
String text_field_text = request.getParameter("text");
```